# What does public access mean in smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

```
contract Coin {
    // The keyword "public" makes variables
    // accessible from other contracts
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // Events allow clients to react to specific
    // contract changes you declare
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    // Constructor code is only run when the contract
    // is created
    constructor() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    // Sends an amount of newly created coins to an address
    // Can only be called by the contract creator
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }

    // Errors allow you to provide information about
    // why an operation failed. They are returned
    // to the caller of the function.
    error InsufficientBalance(uint requested, uint available);

    // Sends an amount of existing coins
    // from any caller to an address
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        if (amount > balances[msg.sender])
            revert InsufficientBalance({
                requested: amount,
                available: balances[msg.sender]
            });

        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

Just look at

```
address public minter;
```

The documentation says

> The keyword public automatically generates a function that allows you
> to access the current value of the state variable from outside of the
> contract. Without this keyword, other contracts have no way to **access**
> the variable. The code of the function generated by the compiler is
> equivalent to the following (ignore external and view for now):

However, it says that other contracts have no way to access the variable.

What does the word "access" here means? Read access? Write access? Read write access?

The reason I ask is because I thought in blockchain everything is readable (though not necessarily writable). However, some of the description suggests only read access.

Answer (score 1):

> *The compiler automatically creates getter functions for all public state variables.*

Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#getter-functions

---

Even though all properties are readable from an offchain source (either by getter function or storage slot, see below), you can limit what other onchain contracts see and how directly offchain apps can read the data.

The `public` [visibility modifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#state-variable-visibility) of a property allows contracts deployed on a different address and offchain apps to read the value. Not to write it. Child contracts can also modify it.

```
contract Parent {
    uint256 public number; // Child can write, others can only read
    uint256 internal otherNumber; // Child can write, others cannot read
    uint256 private anotherNumber; // no other contract can read
}
      
contract Child is Parent {
}
```

If you tried to read the `otherNumber` and `anotherNumber` `private` properties from an offchain app, you'd need to access them through their [storage slot](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_storage.html) IDs, as there are no autogenerated getter functions for these properties. In this specific case, their values are stored in slots 1 and 2 (starting from 0). And they are not accessible from any contract, as they cannot read storage slots directly.